# How should I select only data related to logged user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have class where I inject AppDbContext

```
private readonly AppDbContext context;

    public SQLExpenseRepository(AppDbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
```

I added identity system to my website and now I need to change data so only data related to current logged user will be passed.
This context has context.Categories and I would like to choose only those where user matches with current logged. Is there a way to do this from this constructor or I have to add .Where(...) in every method?

Answer (score 0):

if you using the identity server or any token provider, the easiest way to get user id from user claims and filter the data based on user-id